# Why am I getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: React not defined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, browser, console

I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: React not defined`, this is when I try to use the Chrome browser console to create `var boldElement = React.createElement('b');`. Why might this be happening?

Comment: show some relevant code?

Comment: in your code, try adding `window.React = React`, then use `window.React` in the console

Answer (score 1):

The most basic reason that this might be happening could be how the file structure is created inside of your html.  Check your syntax. It could be an issue where;

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Basic Example</title>
  <script src="/vendor/react.js"></script>
  <script src="/vendor/react-dom.js"></script>
</head>
```

However you need to place a period "." before your file path;

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Basic Example</title>
  <script src="./vendor/react.js"></script>
  <script src="./vendor/react-dom.js"></script>
</head>
```